# My Cherry tree saplings are drying and dying, and I'm not sure why

Tags: plant-health, plant-care, fruit-trees, cherries, outdoor

I have two cherry tree saplings here in Bogotá Colombia. It's sunny and not raining much, with 20 °C (80 °F) During the day, dropping to around 8/9 °C at night (47 °F). I'm watering around a cup of water or a bit more every two or three days depending on how sunny it is. The saplings are in large separate pots in a balcony, behind other pots so as to not suffer from wind. I want to ask if it's too late and if not what steps could be taken, and what seems to be the issue.

[image]

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/S6mrj6V

Comment: This is the pictures folder, any requested angles I'll happily add

Answer (score 1):

They're dying of thirst - I don't know what you mean by a 'cup' but if you mean like a teacupful, that's nowhere near enough, it won't even be reaching the roots. If its 20degC and sunny in the day, they probably need a litre or two every other day if not daily when it's hotter, assuming the pots  have drainage holes for any excess to drain away. Give them a thorough soaking asap, then water properly ongoing.

Comment: Thank you, by cup I meant 250ml roughly. I understand OK thank you, they do have drainage at the bottom of the pot. I just worried about overwatering since they're quite small.

Comment: If there's free drainage from the pots, unless you keep watering when there is torrential rain or the weather is cold and its winter, overwatering is not really a problem in a pot outdoors